# How can I delete an item from a json using the below method?

Tags: python, json

I need to remove data from a json, at the minute i am using the following code:

```
import json
with open('E:/file/timings.json', 'r+') as f:
    qe = json.load(f)
    for item in qe['times']:
        if item['Proc'] == 'APS':
            print(f'{item["Num"]}')
            del item
        json.dump(qe, f, indent=4, sort_keys=False, ensure_ascii=False)
```

This doesn't delete anything from the JSON, here is a small example of my JSON file

```
{
    "times": [
        {
            "Num": "12345678901234567",
            "Start_Time": "2016-12-14 15:54:35",
            "Proc": "UPD",
        },
        {
            "Num": "12345678901234567",
            "Start_Time": "2016-12-08 15:34:05",
            "Proc": "APS",
        },
        {
            "Num": "12345678901234567",
            "Start_Time": "2016-11-30 11:20:21",
            "Proc": "Dev,
```

i would like it to look like this:

```
{
    "times": [
        {
            "Num": "12345678901234567",
            "Start_Time": "2016-12-14 15:54:35",
            "Proc": "UPD",
        },
        {
            "Num": "12345678901234567",
            "Start_Time": "2016-11-30 11:20:21",
            "Proc": "Dev,
```

as you can see the portion containing APS as the process has been removed

Comment: you are not writing anything, overwrite timings.json with the content of json dump

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could save your initial json and then create new one that doesn't contain items which 'Proc' is equal to 'APS' (here `new_json`) and then overwrite your json file with that `new_json`.

```
import json

content = json.loads(open('timings.json', 'r').read())

new_json = {'times': []}

for item in content['times']:
    if item['Proc'] != 'APS':
        new_json['times'].append(item)

file = open('timings.json', 'w')
file.write(json.dumps(new_json, indent=4, sort_keys=False, ensure_ascii=False))
file.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not a good practice to delete element while iterating the list.

**Use:**

```
import json
with open('E:/file/timings.json', 'r') as f:
    qe = json.load(f)

qe = [item for item in qe['times'] if item['Proc'] != 'APS']    #Delete Required element. 

with open('E:/file/timings.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(qe, f, indent=4, sort_keys=False, ensure_ascii=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

`del` as you're using it, removes the variable `item` from your session, but leaves the actual item untouched in the data structure. You need to explicitly remove whatever `item` is pointing to from your data structure. Also, you want to avoid deleting items from a list while you are iterating over said list.  You should recreate your entire list:

```
qe['times'] = [item for item in qe['times'] if item['Proc'] != 'APS']
```

You can use a method if you need to print:

```
def keep_item(thing):
    if item['Proc'] == 'APS':
        print thing['Num']
        return False
    else:
         return True


qe['times'] = [item for item in qe['times'] if keep_item(item)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below method to remove the element from list:

```
for i,item in enumerate(qe['times']):
    if item['Proc'] == 'APS':
        qe['times'].pop(i)
```

and then write back to the JSON file.